# Azure Application Insights with Node.js - monitoring user statistics

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights

I followed the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) for connecting my Node.js application to the Azure Application Insights with just the few basic lines of code:

```
let appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup(process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING).start();
```

After this the requests, response times etc. were collected nicely, but I would like to have information about the users (amount of users, their device type etc). I didn't find any basic examples on how to do that. Any references for a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Created `NodeJS` Application and added code related to Application Insights in `app.js`.

***My `app.js` file :***

```cs
let  appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("Copy the Connection String from Application Insights Instance").start(); 

var  createError = require('http-errors');
var  express = require('express');
var  path = require('path');
var  cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var  logger = require('morgan');
var  indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var  usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var  app = express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended:  false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
next(createError(404));
});
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}; 
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error');
});  
module.exports = app;
```

***My Local Folder Structure :***

[image]

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-overview#send-telemetry-from-your-app) added the `Javascript` function in `index.ejs` which is under `views` folder.

***My `index.ejs` file :***

```cs
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= title %></title>
<link  rel='stylesheet'  href='/stylesheets/style.css'  />
<script  type="text/javascript">
!function(T,l,y){var  S=T.location,k="script",D="instrumentationKey",C="ingestionendpoint",I="disableExceptionTracking",E="ai.device.",b="toLowerCase",w="crossOrigin",N="POST",e="appInsightsSDK",t=y.name||"appInsights";(y.name||T[e])&&(T[e]=t);var  n=T[t]||function(d){var  g=!1,f=!1,m={initialize:!0,queue:[],sv:"5",version:2,config:d};function  v(e,t){var  n={},a="Browser";return  n[E+"id"]=a[b](),n[E+"type"]=a,n["ai.operation.name"]=S&&S.pathname||"_unknown_",n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"]="javascript:snippet_"+(m.sv||m.version),{time:function(){var  e=new  Date;function  t(e){var  t=""+e;return  1===t.length&&(t="0"+t),t}return  e.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+t(1+e.getUTCMonth())+"-"+t(e.getUTCDate())+"T"+t(e.getUTCHours())+":"+t(e.getUTCMinutes())+":"+t(e.getUTCSeconds())+"."+((e.getUTCMilliseconds()/1e3).toFixed(3)+"").slice(2,5)+"Z"}(),iKey:e,name:"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights."+e.replace(/-/g,"")+"."+t,sampleRate:100,tags:n,data:{baseData:{ver:2}}}}var  h=d.url||y.src;if(h){function  a(e){var  t,n,a,i,r,o,s,c,u,p,l;g=!0,m.queue=[],f||(f=!0,t=h,s=function(){var  e={},t=d.connectionString;if(t)for(var  n=t.split(";"),a=0;a<n.length;a++){var i=n[a].split("=");2===i.length&&(e[i[0][b]()]=i[1])}if(!e[C]){var r=e.endpointsuffix,o=r?e.location:null;e[C]="https://"+(o?o+".":"")+"dc."+(r||"services.visualstudio.com")}return e}(),c=s[D]||d[D]||"",u=s[C],p=u?u+"/v2/track":d.endpointUrl,(l=[]).push((n="SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)",a=t,i=p,(o=(r=v(c,"Exception")).data).baseType="ExceptionData",o.baseData.exceptions=[{typeName:"SDKLoadFailed",message:n.replace(/\./g,"-"),hasFullStack:!1,stack:n+"\nSnippet failed to load ["+a+"] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: "+(S&&S.pathname||"_unknown_")+"\nEndpoint: "+i,parsedStack:[]}],r)),l.push(function(e,t,n,a){var i=v(c,"Message"),r=i.data;r.baseType="MessageData";var o=r.baseData;return o.message='AI (Internal): 99 message:"'+("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) ("+n+")").replace(/\"/g,"")+'"',o.properties={endpoint:a},i}(0,0,t,p)),function(e,t){if(JSON){var n=T.fetch;if(n&&!y.useXhr)n(t,{method:N,body:JSON.stringify(e),mode:"cors"});else if(XMLHttpRequest){var a=new XMLHttpRequest;a.open(N,t),a.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json"),a.send(JSON.stringify(e))}}}(l,p))}function i(e,t){f||setTimeout(function(){!t&&m.core||a()},500)}var e=function(){var n=l.createElement(k);n.src=h;var e=y[w];return!e&&""!==e||"undefined"==n[w]||(n[w]=e),n.onload=i,n.onerror=a,n.onreadystatechange=function(e,t){"loaded"!==n.readyState&&"complete"!==n.readyState||i(0,t)},n}();y.ld<0?l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e):setTimeout(function(){l.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e)},y.ld||0)}try{m.cookie=l.cookie}catch(p){}function t(e){for(;e.length;)!function(t){m[t]=function(){var e=arguments;g||m.queue.push(function(){m[t].apply(m,e)})}}(e.pop())}var n="track",r="TrackPage",o="TrackEvent";t([n+"Event",n+"PageView",n+"Exception",n+"Trace",n+"DependencyData",n+"Metric",n+"PageViewPerformance","start"+r,"stop"+r,"start"+o,"stop"+o,"addTelemetryInitializer","setAuthenticatedUserContext","clearAuthenticatedUserContext","flush"]),m.SeverityLevel={Verbose:0,Information:1,Warning:2,Error:3,Critical:4};var s=(d.extensionConfig||{}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics||{};if(!0!==d[I]&&!0!==s[I]){var c="onerror";t(["_"+c]);var u=T[c];T[c]=function(e,t,n,a,i){var r=u&&u(e,t,n,a,i);return!0!==r&&m["_"+c]({message:e,url:t,lineNumber:n,columnNumber:a,error:i}),r},d.autoExceptionInstrumented=!0}return m}(y.cfg);function a(){y.onInit&&y.onInit(n)}(T[t]=n).queue&&0===n.queue.length?(n.queue.push(a),n.trackPageView({})):a()}(window,document,{

src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js", // The SDK URL Source
// name: "appInsights", // Global SDK Instance name defaults to "appInsights" when not supplied
// ld: 0, // Defines the load delay (in ms) before attempting to load the sdk. -1 = block page load and add to head. (default) = 0ms load after timeout,
// useXhr: 1, // Use XHR instead of fetch to report failures (if available),
crossOrigin: "anonymous", // When supplied this will add the provided value as the cross origin attribute on the script tag
// onInit: null, // Once the application insights instance has loaded and initialized this callback function will be called with 1 argument -- the sdk instance (DO NOT ADD anything to the sdk.queue -- as they won't get called)

cfg: { // Application Insights Configuration

instrumentationKey:"INSTRUMENTATION_KEY"

}});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

- Re-deploy the Application and access the URL.

> information about the users (amount of users, their device type etc).

In Azure Portal, navigate to your `Application Insights` Instance => `Users`.
We can see the no. of users accessing the Application.

[image]

- Click on `View more Insights`.

[image]

- Select the required properties.
  [image]

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks! Adding the function to my frontend did the trick. I am serving my frontend build from my backend root endpoint, so I hoped that adding connection between my backend and my Application Insights would have been enough. Now of course the instrumentation key is also available to the end users...