# Azure Application Insight only showing 1 user/session

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I am using React with node.js for my front end and C# for my API back end.

I have an issue with the application insights for the API back end for my app service.  I am only seeing one session and one user. I know this is not the case as I have tested it from two different ip addresses, and logged the results of this.

All the events and errors seem to be getting recorded in the application insight and I can view metrics, events and failures etc...just not more than 1 user or session

I originally setup an application insight resource inside azure and linked this to my API app service, but as this didnt show any more users so I then configured azure app insights into my project in VS, and linked this with the existing Instrumentation Key that I am using

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhGu3aIiMdo&t=109s

I found a similar issue with Counting users https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-monitor/app-insights/usage-troubleshoot#counting-users

relating to `All telemetry events in Application Insights have an anonymous user ID and a session ID as two of their standard properties.  By default, all of the usage analytics tools count the users and sessions based on these IDs. If these properties aren't being populated with unique IDs for each user and session of your app, you'll see an incorrect count of users and sessions in the usage analytics tools.`

So I tried to set this in code behind, well the session ID anyway I couldnt find the anonymous user ID to set.

```
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
telemetryClient.InstrumentationKey = "123";

var ipAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
if (ipAddress == "::1")
{
   ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList[1].ToString();
}

telemetryClient.Context.User.Id = ipAddress;
telemetryClient.Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId = ipAddress;
telemetryClient.Context.Session.Id = ipAddress;


logger.LogInformation("User.Id -> " + ipAddress);
logger.LogInformation("User.AuthenticatedUserId -> " + ipAddress);
logger.LogInformation("Session.Id -> Ip -> " + ipAddress);
```

Then in my Kudu logs I can see:

```
Session.Id -> Ip -> //ip address of first user
...
Session.Id -> Ip -> //ip address of second user
```

but still only one session and one user in the UI dashboard of application insight

any help please?

**UPDATE**
Just to clarify I am running the react node.js on one app service and the C# API on another app service

**UPDATE 2**
User Id and Session Id are always showing as one entry with a
value of `<undefined>`

**UPDATE 3**
Have tried what @DareDevil(API project) and @Harshitha(front end project) suggested.

Both projects are working locally. I can change the telementry code and the resource group and connection string etc.. to match different application insights so one for Dev and one for QA...and both application insights are showing users increasing when run on local VS environment. However when I push the code to the app service it only shows one user which has Id of `<undefined>`

I have put in events to check the status of

```
  telemetry.Context.Session.Id = guid;
```

and the event shows telemetry.Context.Session.Id is NOT NULL so it is populated.

Both projects not picking up the session or user. ANy idea why? Thank you for any more response and thank you for the help so far

@Harshitha
I have ran `npm install applicationinsights --save` which added
"applicationinsights": "^2.7.2", to my project.

Then I have added (to my webpack.js):

```
let  appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("full connection string from app insight portal").start();
```

and added the script to the index.html

```
<script>

!function(T,l,y){var  S=T.location,k="script",D="instrumentationKey",C="ingestionendpoint",I="disableExceptionTracking",E="ai.device.",b="toLowerCase",w="crossOrigin",N="POST",e="appInsightsSDK",t=y.name||"appInsights";(y.name||T[e])&&(T[e]=t);var  n=T[t]||function(d){var  g=!1,f=!1,m={initialize:!0,queue:[],sv:"5",version:2,config:d};function  v(e,t){var  n={},a="Browser";return  n[E+"id"]=a[b](),n[E+"type"]=a,n["ai.operation.name"]=S&&S.pathname||"_unknown_",n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"]="javascript:snippet_"+(m.sv||m.version),{time:function(){var  e=new  Date;function  t(e){var  t=""+e;return  1===t.length&&(t="0"+t),t}return  e.getUTCFullYear()+"-"+t(1+e.getUTCMonth())+"-"+t(e.getUTCDate())+"T"+t(e.getUTCHours())+":"+t(e.getUTCMinutes())+":"+t(e.getUTCSeconds())+"."+((e.getUTCMilliseconds()/1e3).toFixed(3)+"").slice(2,5)+"Z"}(),iKey:e,name:"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights."+e.replace(/-/g,"")+"."+t,sampleRate:100,tags:n,data:{baseData:{ver:2}}}}var  h=d.url||y.src;if(h){function  a(e){var  t,n,a,i,r,o,s,c,u,p,l;g=!0,m.queue=[],f||(f=!0,t=h,s=function(){var  e={},t=d.connectionString;if(t)for(var  n=t.split(";"),a=0;a<n.length;a++){var i=n[a].split("=");2===i.length&&(e[i[0][b]()]=i[1])}if(!e[C]){var r=e.endpointsuffix,o=r?e.location:null;e[C]="https://"+(o?o+".":"")+"dc."+(r||"services.visualstudio.com")}return e}(),c=s[D]||d[D]||"",u=s[C],p=u?u+"/v2/track":d.endpointUrl,(l=[]).push((n="SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)",a=t,i=p,(o=(r=v(c,"Exception")).data).baseType="ExceptionData",o.baseData.exceptions=[{typeName:"SDKLoadFailed",message:n.replace(/\./g,"-"),hasFullStack:!1,stack:n+"\nSnippet failed to load ["+a+"] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: "+(S&&S.pathname||"_unknown_")+"\nEndpoint: "+i,parsedStack:[]}],r)),l.push(function(e,t,n,a){var i=v(c,"Message"),r=i.data;r.baseType="MessageData";var o=r.baseData;return o.message='AI (Internal): 99 message:"'+("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) ("+n+")").replace(/\"/g,"")+'"',o.properties={endpoint:a},i}(0,0,t,p)),function(e,t){if(JSON){var n=T.fetch;if(n&&!y.useXhr)n(t,{method:N,body:JSON.stringify(e),mode:"cors"});else if(XMLHttpRequest){var a=new XMLHttpRequest;a.open(N,t),a.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json"),a.send(JSON.stringify(e))}}}(l,p))}function i(e,t){f||setTimeout(function(){!t&&m.core||a()},500)}var e=function(){var n=l.createElement(k);n.src=h;var e=y[w];return!e&&""!==e||"undefined"==n[w]||(n[w]=e),n.onload=i,n.onerror=a,n.onreadystatechange=function(e,t){"loaded"!==n.readyState&&"complete"!==n.readyState||i(0,t)},n}();y.ld<0?l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e):setTimeout(function(){l.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e)},y.ld||0)}try{m.cookie=l.cookie}catch(p){}function t(e){for(;e.length;)!function(t){m[t]=function(){var e=arguments;g||m.queue.push(function(){m[t].apply(m,e)})}}(e.pop())}var n="track",r="TrackPage",o="TrackEvent";t([n+"Event",n+"PageView",n+"Exception",n+"Trace",n+"DependencyData",n+"Metric",n+"PageViewPerformance","start"+r,"stop"+r,"start"+o,"stop"+o,"addTelemetryInitializer","setAuthenticatedUserContext","clearAuthenticatedUserContext","flush"]),m.SeverityLevel={Verbose:0,Information:1,Warning:2,Error:3,Critical:4};var s=(d.extensionConfig||{}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics||{};if(!0!==d[I]&&!0!==s[I]){var c="onerror";t(["_"+c]);var u=T[c];T[c]=function(e,t,n,a,i){var r=u&&u(e,t,n,a,i);return!0!==r&&m["_"+c]({message:e,url:t,lineNumber:n,columnNumber:a,error:i}),r},d.autoExceptionInstrumented=!0}return m}(y.cfg);function a(){y.onInit&&y.onInit(n)}(T[t]=n).queue&&0===n.queue.length?(n.queue.push(a),n.trackPageView({})):a()}(window,document,{

src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js", // The SDK URL Source
// name: "appInsights", // Global SDK Instance name defaults to "appInsights" when not supplied
// ld: 0, // Defines the load delay (in ms) before attempting to load the sdk. -1 = block page load and add to head. (default) = 0ms load after timeout,
// useXhr: 1, // Use XHR instead of fetch to report failures (if available),
crossOrigin: "anonymous", // When supplied this will add the provided value as the cross origin attribute on the script tag
// onInit: null, // Once the application insights instance has loaded and initialized this callback function will be called with 1 argument -- the sdk instance (DO NOT ADD anything to the sdk.queue -- as they won't get called)

cfg: { // Application Insights Configuration

instrumentationKey:"myRealKey"

}});
    </script>
```

as I said working on local environment, just doesnt work when I deploy app

Comment: As mentioned in the troubleshoot document which you have provided, yes we can add the Javascript SDK and check the no. of users.Refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74958888/19648279)

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Harshitha Yes I read I can use that for the react nodejs. app service for the front end, but I want to know how to see the users for the C# API back end app service, as I will be running .net only applications in the future and will need to know how to do this anyway

Comment: Add the Javascript in any of the cshtml or html file in .net app and check once.

Comment: @Harshitha thank you for the reply my API project has no JS or HTML pages, surely there has to be a more convenient way using only C#?

Comment: Yes, we can add the Javascript SDK and check the no. of users. Refer this

Comment: @Harshitha Thanks for the reply I have tried what you suggested and it is working locally. If I implement let appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup(process.env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING).start(); and update my index.js file with your code.

Comment: It is working locally when I run my code from the dev environment on VS and I can view the users count increase (on the application insights portal) when I use different browsers...however this only works locally when I push to QA or live..... session id is being returned as only one instance with an id of <undefined> (this is same issue for the api) works locally but not when go to different environment. Am I missing something on the setup side of application insights portal perhaps?

Comment: Could you please the code,where you have added InstrumentationKey.

Comment: Have you enabled application Insights in azure app service in portal?For the deployed app it has to be enabled from the portal.

Comment: @Harshitha thanks for reply, please see my updated original Q to include your code. and yes app insights in enabled in app service. I am able to see events and failures and response times etc,,,just no unique users/sessions

Comment: Have you re-deployed the app ?

Comment: In this instance I have published the project over to a VM we are running with IIS to test before I redeploy to app service. But it should still be picking up the users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254932/discussion-between-harshitha-and-john).

Answer (score 2):

You're logging the IP address using logger.LogInformation(), but this won't send telemetry to Application Insights with the session ID you've set. The session ID will only be attached to telemetry sent using the telemetryClient instance as per your given code.

The concept of a session in Application Insights is mainly designed for web applications. While you can use it with APIs, it might not always fit perfectly.

In Web APIs, When telemetry is sent to Application Insights, it can include a Session.Id property. If your telemetry doesn't provide a session ID, Application Insights won't automatically create one for you. This is different from web applications (UI) where the Application Insights JavaScript SDK can automatically generate and manage session IDs based on user activity.

If you want to use the session feature with an API, you'll need to generate session IDs. One common approach is to generate a new session ID for each client that connects to the API and include that ID with all telemetry sent during that client's "session". This can help you track all the actions a specific client takes during a particular period. But since you are only adding application insights to Web APIs, if you want to customize or override the session ID, you can do so by configuring the telemetry initializers.

Here's how you can update the session ID to be used by the telemetry collection behavior in ASP.NET Core:

1. **Create a Custom Telemetry Initializer**:

   - A telemetry initializer allows you to customize telemetry data before it's sent to Application Insights.
   - Create a custom telemetry initializer to set the session ID.

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel;
   using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

   public class CustomSessionTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
   {
       public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
       {
           // Generate or retrieve your custom session ID here
           string customSessionId = "YourCustomSessionId"; // Replace with your logic

           telemetry.Context.Session.Id = customSessionId;
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Register the Custom Telemetry Initializer**:

   - Once you've created the custom telemetry initializer, you need to register it with the Application Insights services in the `Startup.cs` file.

   ```cs
   using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       // ... other services

       services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, CustomSessionTelemetryInitializer>();
       services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help with all that I have tried what you suggested and even added in current dateTime and set it as the customSessionId just so would have unique values. Also set this for Context.Session.Id, Context.User.Id and Context.User.AuthenticatedUserId.

Comment: And it is working I can run the code locally in VS and view the users and session count increase in the application insights section of the azure portal. The only problem it only works on local dev running visual studio When I push the code to QA or Live we are back to where we started. And it only ever registers 1 user & session.What could I be missing?

Comment: Telemetry codes all match up they are copied from application insight and pasted into local code so no typos

Comment: Worth pointing out application insights has been working alone. I have trigged fake 500 errors in the code and this is still working and can be viewed from the failures section, even though the user and session count is not

Comment: If you are logging using LogInformation, After using ITelemetryInitializer as above, are the log entries being showin in Traces? What is the seesionid being registered with traces now?

Comment: I am logging from the controller not the CustomSessionTelemetryInitializer  class. I can view the application insight portal and see the 1 session but when I click 'View More Insights' and the 'select sessions' drop down to show any 5 sessions it says 'The query returned no results'

Comment: Funny enough I have just looked at another site we have setup as an app service which I know hasnt been used in about a week. All the requests are coming in the last 24 hours as 0 which is correct but it is still showing as 1 user in the users section. Im guessing this is the same issue

Comment: OK was able to select User Id and Authenticated user Id from the drop downs in the user section in the azure portal and I can see when I temp set the ids earlier in the day they are correctly showing however now the only user id that is the 1 that is constantly showing is set to <undefined> which would explain why its always 1. as not being updated. Do you know how to fix this or point me in the right direction please?